# require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2 (LoadError) rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I trying run 'rails s' in a project, but I get an unexpected error :S. 
Thanks in advance............................. 
................................

```
➜  backend-ror git:(dev) ✗ rails s                                                                               
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2 (LoadError)
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Gudi/backend-ror/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from ./bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from ./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
´´´sudo gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.19 -- \ --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.37/bin/mysql_config \ --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib \ --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include ´´´
```